# Why is using an implicit intent to start a service not safe?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

When I start a service with an implicit intent I get a warning:

> Implicit intents with startservice are not safe: ...

Why?

**Edit:**

I am using my own internal category that no other application should use and my service is not exported `android:exported="false"`.

Comment: to protect from collision... Other apps may have `Service`s accepting same intent action...

Comment: @GopalRao but not if I use an application-specific category.

Comment: but what if category collision occurs? (A very very rare situation). Android system will not ask the user to choose which Service to start...

Comment: That sounds like an Android bug or oversight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By Using  `Implicit Intents` you have not specified a component, It means the component will be chosen by `Android` by given `Intent-Action`.

Using `android:exported="false"` will make sure that, other can not start your service. But what if I wrote an application with `BroadcastReeciver` which listens your `Intent-Action` and do some malicious work?

And same would happen when I declared a Service into my application and use the same category/ filter/ action.

So use `Explicit Intents`.

Comment: I use an internal category that my someday be public.

Comment: I don't care if you've added a "malicious" application that picks up my service intents, what are you going to do... log when my service is started?  You can just ask the system that.  There is no sensitive data in my intent.

Comment: Then no worry about that. That is only a warning, you can ignore that :)

Comment: @PankajKumar I am using android license checking code (LVL), for that binding service using this "new Intent("com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService")". Getting same warning and service not start. Happening only for 4.0 and up devices.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  This is the entire point of intents, allowing you to specify what you want done rather than who you want to do it, so the user can choose which app to use for a task.  Forcing apps to include the component name defeats the whole point.  And it's not "only a warning", 5.0 breaks this entirely.

Comment: @BipinVayalu I know I'm a little late, but have you ever solved this issue? I too have implemented the Google Play Licensing check code (using a book and the Google documentation as references) and I am getting this warning too (in [tag:Logcat]; it actually throws an exception and says something like "License Check Service Has Stopped"). I am using Android 5.1.1 (API 22). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @clamum ok np, you also need to set package name in service binding intent. if not work please share your licensing code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Service(s) with the same IntentFilter, System do not know which one should be started, and system will not ask users to choose.