# Retrieving the component name of a service defined in another Xamarin application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently implementing an Android Service which is to be consumed by another application of a partner company. They implement the frontend GUI, we do the business logic inside the Service.

The Service is declared like this:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "PsiServiceHost" })]
public class PsiServiceHost : Service
{
...
}
```

The consuming application (optionally) starts the service and connects to it using this Intent:

```
serviceIntent = new Intent("PsiServiceHost");
```

Starting the service using ...

```
ApplicationContext.StartService(serviceIntent);
```

... results in the following log output:

> 08-16 10:38:17.182  3429  3429 W ContextImpl: Implicit intents with
>   startService are not safe: Intent { act=PsiServiceHost }
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581
>   md5db25c5914f35662b07cd28205cc94074.MainActivity.n_onCreate:-2
>   md5db25c5914f35662b07cd28205cc94074.MainActivity.onCreate:29

According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27308675/88513), starting Services using implicit intents is no longer possible even though it works fine in my case on Android 6.0 running on the Emulator.

Anyway, just to be safe I would like to use the recommended approach of constructing my Intent using a ComponentName. This would be no problem for code residing in the same project as the service as I could do this and be done with it:

```
Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(PsiServiceHost)).CanonicalName
```

But unless the result from the above line of can be considered to be stable and safe to be included as string in another App, I don't know how provide the consuming App with the component Name of our Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Application with the Service:

Package Name = `com.sushihangover.androidservice`

```
[Service(Name="com.sushihangover.androidservice.MyMostAmazingService", Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new String[] { "myservice" }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class PsiServiceHost : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug("SO", "MyMostAmazingService Has Been Started");
        return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

The other application starting `MyMostAmazingService`:

```
var intent = new Intent();
// Package name first, Service Class Name Second
intent.SetClassName("com.sushihangover.androidservice", "com.sushihangover.androidservice.MyMostAmazingService");
StartService(intent);
```

Comment: Would +2 because of Sushihangover :)