# Launching a second Application in Android and passing data to it and receiving data back

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent

I'm using Xamarin C# here.

I have an Android application, *app A*, and I would like to launch it from a second application, *app B*, passing some data into it.
This will dictate which operations to perform and what data to return.

When *app A* is finished, I would like to return said data to *app B*.

Currently, *app B* launches *app A* via StartActivityForResult, and awaits the response with OnActivityResult:

```
PackageManager pm = PackageManager;
Intent intent = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("Application.A");
intent.SetAction("Task_1");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.PutString("Activity", "BundleActivity");
StartActivityForResult(intent, (int)ActivityCode.Task1, bundle);
```

This correctly launches *app A* and allows me to determine that we need to do Task_1 (via the action, I've not tried the bundle).

When *app A* is done it performs the following:

```
var returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.PutExtra("AppBData", the_data_obj);
SetResult(Result.Ok, returnIntent);
Finish();
```

This is detected by *app B* and caught in the OnActivityResult:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch ((ActivityCode)requestCode)
    {
        case ActivityCode.Task1:
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                Java.Lang.Object dataReturned = data.GetParcelableExtra("AppBData");
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

but 'data' is always null.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Not had a chance to try, I will be checking shortly, but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your way to start ApplicationB, and the value of `resultCode` is also `Canceled`.

So don't use `Intent intent = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("Application.A");` to get the `Intent`, use `SetClassName` method to select which component you will start:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.SetClassName("ApplicationB.ApplicationB", "ApplicationB.ApplicationB.MainActivity");
intent.PutExtra("Activity", "BundleActivity");
intent.PutExtra("Operation", "Task_1");
StartActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

And thanks @SushiHangover's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38973871/8632294), you need add `Name="ApplicationB.ApplicationB.MainActivity"` above your ApplicationB's ManiActivity.

I have post the [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/AOpenB) on github, there are two applications, ApplicationA and ApplicationB, run ApplicationB and then run ApplicationA, the A will open B and there is a button in B, click it, you will back to A and get the data from B.

Comment: This works exactly as I needed, thank you!

I only seem to be able to launch the main activity (Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent), but I can launch the correct one from there, so it's not a big problem.